# How to convert a weird string to integer

Tags: python

Sorry for the possible repeats of the question. I have a weird string, for example:

```
'[23, 14, 34]'
```

ps: there is a comma "," and a space " " separating each number. The whole thing is recognized as string.
I want to convert it into a list of integers:

```
[23, 14, 34]
```

Any insights? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: You could also use the `json` module to parse the string.

Comment: Another method would be: `x[1:-1].split(', ')`, then convert to ints~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using json.loads()

```
import json

ini_list = "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
print ("initial string", ini_list)
print (type(ini_list))
res = json.loads(ini_list)
print ("final list", res)
print (type(res))
```